# Differents coordinates for the same place

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, cllocationmanager

i try to use CLLocationmanager to get the  GOS coordinates of the user 
My problem is that when i run the application severals times, i get diffrents results

Examples :
first time   (48.839780, 2.322400)
second time  (48.836476, 2.324006)

can i do some thing to improve the precision

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just down to noise and inaccuracies in the fine precision data.

You could improve this slightly by using a noise reducing algorithm which smoothes the changes in the data.

Take a look at [this Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter). I did something similar to this to try to minimise the fluctuations I was getting in the readings of the device orientation.

Comment: the difference can be up to 300 meters, normal ??